# Assign a repeated sequence to an index in python

Tags: python

I am very new to `python` and I wanted to know, how can I assign an integer incrementally to every `3 values` in a series. Might be better to explain with an example:

The result should contain the following pattern :

`(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2),(5,2),(6,2),(7,3).......`

Comment: Would be great if you could show what you've tried :)

Comment: Maybe try nesting a for loop inside another for loop. If you are new to for loops, [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) is a pretty good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, just using a simple for loop and two variables:

```
val1 = 1
val2 = 1
for a in range(10): # this number is arbitrarily large
    for b in range(3): # this number is not arbitrary
        print( (val1, val2) )
        val1 += 1
    val2 += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the floor division operator with a list comprehension:

```
n = range(1, 10)
res = [(i, idx//3 + 1) for idx, i in enumerate(n)]

print(res)

[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1),
 (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 2),
 (7, 3), (8, 3), (9, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be infinite, I'd suggest looking into the utilities in `itertools`

```
from itertools import count

def integers_rep(n):
    for i in count(1):
        for _ in range(n):
            yield i

def gen_sequence():
    return zip(count(1), integers_rep(3))
```

`count(n)` is an iterable which will yield the sequence `n, n+1, n+2, ...` ad infinitum  starting at it's first argument (which defaults to 0 if nothing is passed).

`gen_sequence` which would create your sequence, uses `zip` which takes N-iterables and produces a sequence of N-tuples (two sequences => pairs, three => triples, etc.). By taking `count` and the other sequence, you will be able to then get their pairs.

By using these tools, you would be able to define everything at a high level (which can be useful for mathematical sequences).